# How to Split Json format column values in Spark dataframe using foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I want to split the JSON format column results in a Spark dataframe:

`allrules_internal` table in Hive :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|tablename  |                 condition            | filter     |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
| documents | {"col_list":"document_id,comments"}  | NA         |
| person    | {"per_list":"person_id, name, age"}  | NA         |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
val allrulesDF = spark.read.table("default" + "." + "allrules_internal")
allrulesDF.show()

val df1 = allrulesDF.select(allrulesDF.col("tablename"), allrulesDF.col("condition"), allrulesDF.col("filter"), allrulesDF.col("dbname")).collect()
```

Here I want to split the `condition` column values. From the example above, I want to keep the "document_id, comments" part. In other words, the condition column have a key/value pair but I only want the value part.

If more than one row in `allrules_internal` table how to split the value.

```
  df1.foreach(row => { 
     //   condition = row.getAs("condition").toString() // here how to retrive ?
       println(condition)
       val tableConditionDF = spark.sql("SELECT "+ condition + " FROM " + db_name + "." + table_name)
       tableConditionDF.show()
 })
```

Comment: Will the condition column always have a single key-value pair and will the key always be `col_list`? Maybe you can add a couple of more rows to the input table in the question.

Comment: edited question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `from_json`function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

allrulesDF
  .withColumn("condition", from_json($"condition", StructType(Seq(StructField("col_list", DataTypes.StringType, true)))))
  .select($"tablename", $"condition.col_list".as("condition"))
```

It will print:

```
+---------+---------------------+
|tablename|condition            |
+---------+---------------------+
|documents|document_id, comments|
+---------+---------------------+
```

Explanation:

With the `withColumn` method, you can create a new column by using a function combining one or more columns. In this case, we're using the `from_json` function, which receives the column that contains a JSON String, and a `StructType` object, with the schema of the JSON string represented in the column. Finally, you just have to select the columns you that need.

Hope it helped!

Comment: If I have more than one row in the allrules_internal table how to add?   
             df1.foreach(row => {   condition = allrulesDF
  .withColumn(row.getAs("condition"), from_json($"condition", StructType(Seq(StructField("col_list", DataTypes.StringType, true)))))
  .select($"condition.col_list".as("condition"))
  
   //   condition = row.getAs("condition").toString()
      println(condition)
      val tableConditionDF = spark.sql("SELECT "+ condition + " FROM " + db_name + "." + table_name)
      tableConditionDF.show() })

Comment: edited question